# incorrect signature: void valueOf() from the type Datetime unittest

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, json, code-coverage

I have a rest API which I am trying to write a unittest for. I get the error: incorrect signature: void valueOf() from the type Datetime unittest. Please some help

Rest API:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/invoices/*')
global with sharing class InvoiceManager {
   @HttpPost
    global static ID createInvoice (
        String customerId,
        String addressId,
        String invoiceId,
        String invoiceType,
        String invoiceTypeLocalized,
        String invoiceDate,
        String paymentDueDate,
        String invoiceNumber,
        String startDate,
        String endDate,
        String periodDescription,
        Double amount,
        Double vatAmount,
        Double totalAmount 
    ) {
        invoice__c thisinvoice = new invoice__c (
            customerId__c = customerId,
            addressId__c = addressId,
            invoiceId__c = invoiceId,
            invoiceType__c = invoiceType,
            invoiceTypeLocalized__c = invoiceTypeLocalized,
            invoiceDate__c = Date.valueOf(invoiceDate.replace('T',' ')),
            paymentDueDate__c = Date.valueOf(paymentDueDate.replace('T',' ')),
            invoiceNumber__c = invoiceNumber,
            startDate__c = Date.valueOf(startDate.replace('T',' ')),
            endDate__c = Date.valueOf(endDate.replace('T',' ')),
            periodDescription__c = periodDescription,
            amount__c = amount,
            vatAmount__c = vatAmount,
            totalAmount__c = totalAmount
        );
        insert thisInvoice;
        return thisInvoice.Id;
    }   
}
```

Test:

```
@IsTest
private class InvoiceManagerTest {

     @isTest static void testCreateInvoice() {
        // Call the method to test
        ID thisInvoiceId = InvoiceManager.createInvoice(         '1','8212BJ154','70ec3a54a43d014aa9e8','AdvancePayment','Voorschot',Datetime.valueOf(2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z),
                                    '2015-02-20T00:00:00','157005888','2015-03-01T00:00:00','2015-04-01T00:00:00','Maart 2015',
                                    165.29,34.71,200.00);
      // Verify results
      System.assert(thisInvoiceId != null);
      Invoice__c thisInvoice = [SELECT Id,customerId__c FROM Invoice__c WHERE Id=:thisInvoiceId];
      System.assert(thisInvoice != null);
      System.assertEquals(thisInvoice.customerId__c, '1');
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you meant to pass in the datetime as a String? Instead of `'Voorschot',Datetime.valueOf(2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z),`, pass `'Voorschot','2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z',`

Comment: @BorisBachovski Itried InvoiceManager.createInvoice(
          '1','8212BJ154','70ec3a54a43d014aa9e8','AdvancePayment','Voorschot','2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z',
                                    '2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z','157005888','2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z','2015-02-13T00:00:00.000z','Maart 2015',
                                    '165.29','34.71','200.00') but get does noet exist or incorrect signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my class I replaced double with decimal

```
Decimal amount,
   Decimal vatAmount,
   Decimal totalAmount
```

This error was because of my class an testmethod didnt have the same signature

Example Class vs Unittest(Good)

```
string string
Decimal Decimal
```

Example Class vs Unittest(Bad)

```
string string
Decimal double
```